# "EmptyHeader" in CSV Export Options?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a CSV file I am attempting to create, and the recipient requires a header row. In this header row (and in the data) there is a field that used to be present that was removed. However, they did not remove the column that that held that data, so now, there is an empty column name surrounded by delimiters ("|"). How can I recreate this?

The expected results for the following columns should be:

```
RxType1|RxType2|RxType3|RxType4|RxType5||DelivID
```

(There is an empty column between RxType5 and DelivID) and the results would be:

```
|Rx|OTC|Legend|Generic|Other||Express
```

I am using SSRS, and have attempted adding an extra pipe the the column header for RxType5 with an empty column behind it, but the CSV seems to generate a header row based on the column names from the stored procedure and not from the RDL data. I have also attempted in the Stored Proc to create the column by using:

```
Select
'' AS ""
```

OR

```
'' AS "|"
```

but when I refresh the fields in SSRS, it puts that the column is called "ID_" (because a space, no character, or pipe is non-CLS compliant.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Thanks so much :)

Comment: before i did postprocessing in the caller process is used to write rendering extension which tapped into the original rendering extensions via reflection, got the content (in your case a csv )and then modify it. if you're interested in that, i can create a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the column with a known name, like `SELECT '' AS [RemoveMe]`, and then just remove that name from the row header text box.

Comment: Remove the row header text box on the RDL file in Visual Studio? That does not work. The CSV will still say RxText5|RemoveMe|Express in that scenario, regardless of what I do to the header row on the RDL.